# Why does the size of raw_image equal the sensor size?

Tags: python, rawimage, rawpy

I would like to access the intensity of individual color pixels within the RGGB-Bayer pattern of my Sony camera. With the rawpy package it seems like I can obtain the raw_image, but it is a 2D-array of the shape (4024, 6048), which is the size of the sensor. Shouldn't the array contain RGGB-data for each pixel, and therefore have the shape (8048, 12096)?

```
import rawpy

im_raw = rawpy.imread('Test.ARW').raw_image
print(np.shape(im_raw))
```

Comment: it may be hard for one to answer you without a sample raw file. 
Meanwhile, what value you get at each pixel? 
Maybe it is a 48bit value? or an array of 4 values? You can introspect that as wll and gain some insight.

Comment: print(type(im_raw[0,0])) gives <class 'numpy.uint16'>, so neither 48 bit nor an array...

Answer (score 0):

Each pixel of a bayer-pattern sensor is *either* red, green or blue, and there are as many greens as there are reds and blues together. There is not full colour info for every pixel. To make a full RGB image, the three components need to be interpolated to fill out the gaps.

Comment: What does the value 517 at index [0,0] mean, then? Intensity at a red subpixel? And 515 at index [1,0] the intensity at a green subpixel? In this case I would only have 2012 red subpixels vertically, instead of 4024?

Answer (score 0):

The `RawPy` object created by `rawpy.imread` has, in parallel to the pixel values in the `.raw_image` array you are looking at, another `.raw_colors` attribute: a second array with a number corresponding to each pixel - in the case of your sample image, they go from 0 to 3 - I assume each of these numbers is a color channel.

Maybe the other attributes of the `RawPy` object have more information about how to map these indices to color channels - otherwise, just checking the libraw or Sony resources for information on this raw format, or, otherwise experimenting with the channels.

As for the sensor size X image pixel size: it is just that - you have this color info for this subpixel, and Sony, pyraw and other software have the means to build an RGB image out of that. (call the .postprocess() method on the RawPy object to get a uint8 4k x 6k RGB image)